# Remove all characters after a particular character

Tags: java

I have  words like:

```
Sams – like costco
Jecy penny ? like sears
```

In Java I want to take this string and get the out put as:

```
Sams 
Jecy penny
```

Is there any way I can remove all characters after `-` and `?`?

Comment: One of the way is using String class [split method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) another is using [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 6):

Three options:

- Use `indexOf` and then `substring`
- Use `split` and then take the first return value
- Use regular expressions to replace everything after the first part

Here's the split option - bear in mind that `split` takes a regular expression:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showFirstPart("Sams - like costco");
        showFirstPart("Jecy penny ? like sears");
    }

    private static void showFirstPart(String text) {
        String[] parts = text.split("[-?]", 2);
        System.out.println("First part of " + text
                           + ": " + parts[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon did not work...for the following:  String text1 = " Sams Best – costco is ok "; the answer is same. I was not able to remove after -

Answer (score 2):

**1.**    `Sams - like costco`

**Answer:**

```
String s = "Sams - like costco";

String[] arr = s.split("-");

String res = arr[0];
```

**2.**    `Jecy penny ? like sears`

**Answer:**

```
String s = "Jecy penny ? like sears";

String[] arr = s.split("\\?");  

Added \\ before ?, as ? has a special meaning

String res = arr[0];
```

**Though the above 2 examples are for those with only one "-" and  "?", you can do this for multiple "-" and "?" too**

[image: THE OUTPUT]

Comment: I tried  String[] arr = text.split("-");
     String res = arr[0]; and the text is = Sams Best – costco is ok . It did not work

Comment: yes did not work String text1 = " Sams Best – costco is ok ";
   
    String[] arr = text1.split("-");

    String res = arr[0];
    System.out.println(res);===output is  Sams Best – costco is ok

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, i forgot to add the "\\" character before ?, see my edited answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()` method

```
String str = "Sams – like costco";
    String str1 = "Jecy penny ? like sears";

    String[] arr = str.split("–");
    String arr1[] = str1.split("\\?");
    System.out.println(arr[0]);
    System.out.println(arr1[0]);
```

Comment: I tried the input string as : Sams Best – costco is ok and it did not work

Comment: I checked o/p->`Sams Best`. What is expected for you?

Comment: hmm. am I missing  some thing..    String text1 = " Sams Best – costco is ok ";

    remove(text1);
and the function is  private static void remove(String text) {
         String[] parts = text.split("-");
         System.out.println(parts[0]);
     }
 out put is : Sams Best – costco is ok

Comment: Use : `private static void remove(String text) { 
  String[] parts = text.split("–"); 
  System.out.println(parts[0]); 
 }`

Comment: you used `-` and not `–`, these are two different chars

Comment: Thankq this worked is there a way I can give both in one one?>

Comment: what is your combined string?

Comment: combined regex for both : `String[] arr = str.split("[–[\\?]]");`

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed that you want to remove the word `"like"` and the following word after either `"-"` or `"?"`...

Here's how you do it in one line:

```
String output = input.replaceAll( "(?i)[-?]\\s*like\\s+\\b.+?\\b", "" );
```

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    String input = "Sams - like costco Jecy penny ? like sears";
    String output = input.replaceAll( "(?i)[-?]\\s*like\\s+\\b.+?\\b", "" );
    System.out.println( output );
}
```

Output:

```
Sams  Jecy penny
```