# Extract characters after ?= in link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can anyone see where I going wrong here, I'm trying to get the last characters after the ?p= in a link and put in a varaible, but the code I'm using returns /.

My code is:

```
 $("#dvPartial").on('click', '.dvPagerCities a', function (event) {
        alert('click detected');
        var city = ($('input#hdnCountry').val());
        alert(city);
        var link = $('a').attr('href');
        //var getEqualPosition = link.indexOf('?p='); //Get the position of '='
        var getEqualPosition = link.indexOf('='); //Get the position of '='
        var number = link.substring(getEqualPosition + 1); //Split the string and get the number.
```

My link is

```
<a href="/Weather/Index/Australia?p=2">»</a>
```

I think what is happening is its picking up the 1st = .

My theory is this.

1) Detect the click event

2) Get the link that caused the event

3) Extract the value of p,

p can be 1 diget, 2 digets or 3 digets.

Any help would be appreciated, as it seems no sooner do I solve 1 problem then another arises.

Thanks

George

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: It works fine for me. See this example http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/7QHr4/

Comment: Hi Dineshkani its does work in jsfiddle, or a static link outside the partial update but not on my page when the links is created

Comment: see the fiddle in the answer.

Comment: @Jai It works in that jsFiddle because you only have a single link, and therefore the incorrect `var link = $('a').attr('href');` line just happens to select the correct link.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist yes you are right just updated the fiddle and the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `p` is the only parameter in the URL you can simply split by the `=` sign:

```
$("#dvPartial").on('click', '.dvPagerCities a', function (event) {
    var city = $('input#hdnCountry').val();
    var number = $(this).attr('href').split('=')[1];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this part:

```
var link = $('a').attr('href');
```

That does **not** select the link that was clicked, unless you happen to be clicking the very first link present in the HTML of the page. What that will do is select **all** `<a>` elements, then return the `href` attribute of the first one.

Inside your event handler, you want to use `this` to refer to the link that was clicked:

```
var link = $(this).attr('href');
// or simply
var link = this.href;
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, that for the theory, i'm having to learn a lot in a short space of time, awarded a point up for teaching me something, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

`link.split('?p=')[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/7atyG/1/

```
$(document).on('click', '.dvPagerCities a', function (ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   var link = $(this).attr('href');
   var Linkval = link.substr(link.indexOf('=') + 1);
   alert(Linkval);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "Jecy penny ? like sears";

String[] arr = s.split("\\?");  

Added \\ before ?, as ? has a special meaning

String res = arr[0];
```

May be you are wrong at escape character for ' ? '

check this link [Remove all characters after a particular character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000524/remove-all-characters-after-a-particular-character)